# I want to take a certain interger from a string

Tags: java

I want to turn a string into an interger but only part of it.

Say I have a string of "123, 321, 45", and I only want the number after the second comma in this case 45, and I want to do this even if I don't know the other numbers is there a way to accomplish this?

If it helps this is how i'm currently compiling the string.

```
    String numbers = new String(double1+","+double2+","+interger);

    return numbers;
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Hey James Marshall, don't mind this guy. It looks like you're writing in Java, and even so this is an algorithm problem so you can write it in any language

Comment: Hi James, don't mind the that last guy (Mitch Kroska) - Java and Javascript are totally different (as Jam and James) - use the correct tags for your question, not only to help getting a correct answer faster, but also to help other people having similar questions!

Comment: You want the integer after the second comma. Looking at your shown code, that integer should already be the value of your variable `interger`. Please explain why you want to readit out of the compiled string again. If you would make a [mre] of the code which fills the string, it would probably help to clarify the background. Interesting would for example whether `interger`contains a string or an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a list from comma-separated string and then access numbers in the list
`str="123, 321, 45";`
`List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));` 
you would get 45 like this
`items[2]`

Comment: just to complete, `\\s*` is used to eliminate eventual empy spacces

Answer (score 1):

```
String list = new String(double1 + ", " + double2 + ", " + integer);
String[] numbers = list.split(",\\s*"); // This split accounts for commas with and without whitespaces in front of them.
```

Then grab whichever number you wanted from whichever index it's at (or, if your goal is to find the index at which the number occurs, search the array using a for loop until you get to the position within the array where the number occurs. Then increase the value of the position by 1 and you'll have the value for the position in the string that the value occurs at.) and use:

```
Integer.valueOf(numbers[index]);
```

And you'll be able to return/print that number (by either just returning that entire line or encasing it within a print function).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

**1. splitting the string by comma:**

```
`String[] values = numbers.split(","); `
```

this will look like: `["123", "321", "45"]`

**2. grabbing the last element of the `.split(",")` created array []:**

```
 `String lastNum = values[2]`
```

> note: arrays start at zero, so the 3rd element is actually the 2nd as
>   in [0,1,2]

this will look like "45"

> ```
>  quotes around the number say that it's a String not an Integer
> ```

**3. convert lastNum(which is a String) to an Int:**

```
 `Integer result = Integer.valueOf(lastNum);`
```

this will look like 45

```
    note: no quotes: "", meaning it's an Integer: 45
```

**4. Print out final value:**

> which is an Integer(45) not a String("")

```
`System.out.println(result);`
```

> ```
>  the output will be, 45 // no quotes, which means it's an Integer
> ```

Comment: and probably get a `NumberFormatException`... `" 45"` is not a valid integer

Comment: This is why people hate using stackoverflow...

Comment: incomplete/wrong, double answers?

Comment: " 45" was probably a typo...